# MySQL Join table and get results that don't exist in one

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables, one that has a foreign key from the other.  I want to get all records that don't exist in the foreign table, based on certain criteria.

Here are the tables I have:

**item_setting**

- setting_id
- category_id

**item**

- item_id
- setting_id
- name
- expired_dt

Here's the query I'm using now:

```
SELECT 
    iset.setting_id
FROM
    item_settings iset
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    item i ON i.setting_id = iset.setting_id
WHERE
    iset.category_id = '5' AND i.setting_id is null
```

This query works in providing any setting_id's that do not have a record in the item's table within a specific category.

However, now I want to include cases where the expired_dt less than than time() (meaning it's past expired).  In otherwords, I would think to add this:

```
WHERE
    iset.category_id = '5' AND (i.setting_id is null OR i.expired_dt < '".time()."')
```

However, this doesn't work, it returns all the records.

Any suggestions? Maybe I'm completely over complicating this....  I just want to return the setting_id's from the item_settings table, where the expired_dt associated in the item table is expired or if it does not even exist in the item table.

Thank you!

Comment: What column type is expired_dt?

Comment: Your where clause looks fine, however the i.expired_dt < '".time()."' condition is really strange, please check that is not true for every value in your expired_dt column

Comment: is expired_dt always non-null?

Comment: the time() is a php timestamp, the column is an int that stores a unix timestamp.

Comment: Ok, it looks like the problem is when there are duplicate records in the 'item' table, with the same setting_id (which will often be the case)... hm

Comment: Have you tried my solution? I'm 95% sure it will help your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the timestamp condition into the join clause. Something like

```
item_settings iset
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    item i ON i.setting_id = iset.setting_id and i.expired_dt > time()
```

Comment: This throws an error if there are no records in the items table.  The issue is when records do exist in the item table that have already been expired and not-expired.  It should only have one record at a time that is not yet expired...

Comment: Well, without being able to see your data and output, I can't help you much more. The join condition I listed is basically saying join only when there's a corresponding non-expired item, so the left join filter should list every other setting.

Comment: You got it right! :) I had something wrong... just silly mistake.  Thank you!